# What to do when getting "Could not authenticate you from facebook beacause 'Csrf detected'?

Tags: infamous-paper-trail

I'm getting the below error message:

> Could not authenticate you from Facebook because "Csrf detected"...

What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do much. That's a problem caused by the use of Omniauth on the developer side.

If you can figure it out, here is the issue's link on GitHub:

https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/issues/73

Comment: Also, I posted a bug report. Should be fixed @ the next update.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION that worked for me:

- Clearing computer temps and cache, and clearing the browser.
- Reopening app. CSFR is a Cross Site Request Forgery. So, in this case, either it is a real attack happening or the site/app OKTA SSO verification system just thinks there is a Csfr going on.  If it is not a Persistent attack, then clearing the cache/temps and browser and reopening might do. If not, do that but also restart computer.
- Do clear cache but switch browser/app if possible for what is intended.
- Last but not least, if none of that worked, give your computer and network a thorough check up, might be actually infected.

Of course, you could also just report the issue from beginning but might have to wait. I did the steps I stated here and it work for me without need of escalation.